# multiple instances mysql on ubuntu error

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have been trying to make multiple instances of mysql on ubuntu. These are the steps I followed.

```
mv /etc/init.d/mysql /etc/init.d/mysql_mono.server
cp /usr/share/mysql/mysqld_multi.server /etc/init.d/mysql
```

With your favourite text editor, edit /etc/init.d/mysql, then find the lines:

```
basedir=/usr/local/mysql
bindir=/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

And change to:

```
basedir=/usr
bindir=/usr/bin
```

If your have a root password in localhost, edit the file /usr/bin/mysqld_multi, then find the line:

```
$opt_password = undef()
```

And change to:

```
$opt_password = "password"
```

changing "password" by the 'root'@'localhost' password.

Now create a database directory for each additional mysqld instance:

```
# cp -pr /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql1
# cp -pr /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql2
```

My configuration file(my.cnf) is:

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0



[mysqld1]
user = root
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld1.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld1.sock
port = 3301
datadir = /var/lib/mysql1
log = /var/log/mysql/mysql1.log
server-id = 1
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql1-bin.log

[mysqld2]
user = root
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld2.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld2.sock
port = 3302
datadir = /var/lib/mysql2
log = /var/log/mysql/mysql2.log
server-id = 2
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql2-bin.log


# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1

log_error                = /var/log/mysql/error.log


[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M


``!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Still I get this error when i run following command:

```
mysql --socket=/var/run/mysqld1.sock -uroot


ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld1.sock' (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

via http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-unix-servers.html

> One way is to run multiple MySQL instances on Unix is to compile
>   different servers with different default TCP/IP ports and Unix socket
>   files so that each one listens on different network interfaces.
>   Compiling in different base directories for each installation also
>   results automatically in a separate, compiled-in data directory, log
>   file, and PID file location for each server.
>
> Assume that an existing 5.1 server is configured for the default
>   TCP/IP port number (3306) and Unix socket file (/tmp/mysql.sock). To
>   configure a new 5.5.35 server to have different operating parameters,
>   use a CMake command something like this:

```
shell> cmake . -DMYSQL_TCP_PORT=port_number \
             -DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=file_name \
             -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/mysql-5.5.35
```